# Vim delay with cw commands

Tags: vim, editing

I'm having an issue with some vim commands that replace words, specifically after movement commands like e, w and b.

Specifically, there is always a delay for cw, but not for ci" for example to change text within quotes.

Secondly, if I move three words forward, and type cw to change the third word without waiting a bit, it moves another word forward and cw's that one.

I've cut out a lot out of my Vimrc, and I can't really tell what might be causing the issue. Many times I end up doing a viw then c to change the word quickly, which doesn't make sense to me. Any insight into the issue would be fantastic.

Also, this is not system dependent, It's consistent across three different computers, nor is it syntax/filetype specific.

```
autocmd!
set nocompatible                                                                                                                
filetype off

set rtp+=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

Bundle 'nanotech/jellybeans.vim'
Bundle 'bling/vim-airline'

Bundle 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'

Bundle 'bitc/vim-bad-whitespace'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'

Bundle 'mileszs/ack.vim'

Bundle 'othree/html5.vim'

Bundle 'juvenn/mustache.vim'

Bundle 'yaymukund/vim-rabl'
Bundle 'int3/vim-extradite'

Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-haml'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-endwise'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-eunuch'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-markdown'

Bundle 'kein/ctrlp.vim'
Bundle 'wincent/Command-T'

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" BASIC EDITING CONFIGURATION
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
set nocompatible
" allow unsaved background buffers and remember marks/undo for them
set hidden
" remember more commands and search history
set nu
set history=10000
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
set laststatus=2
set showmatch
set incsearch
set hlsearch
set t_Co=256
" make searches case-sensitive only if they contain upper-case characters
set ignorecase smartcase
" highlight current line
set cursorline
set cmdheight=1
set switchbuf=useopen
set showtabline=2
set winwidth=79
" This makes RVM work inside Vim. I have no idea why.
set shell=bash
" Prevent Vim from clobbering the scrollback buffer. See
" http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html
set t_ti= t_te=
" keep more context when scrolling off the end of a buffer
set scrolloff=3
" Store temporary files in a central spot
set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
set directory=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start
" display incomplete commands
set showcmd
" Enable highlighting for syntax
syntax on
" Enable file type detection.
" Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
" 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
" Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
filetype plugin indent on
" use emacs-style tab completion when selecting files, etc
set wildmode=longest,list
" make tab completion for files/buffers act like bash
set wildmenu
let mapleader=","
" Fix slow O inserts
:set timeout timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=100
" Normally, Vim messes with iskeyword when you open a shell file. This can
" leak out, polluting other file types even after a 'set ft=' change. This
" variable prevents the iskeyword change so it can't hurt anyone.
let g:sh_noisk=1
" Modelines (comments that set vim options on a per-file basis)
set modeline
set modelines=3
" Turn folding off for real, hopefully
set foldmethod=manual
set nofoldenable

let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_fugitive_prefix = ' '
let g:airline_readonly_symbol = ''
let g:airline_linecolumn_prefix = ''
let g:airline_theme='badwolf'

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" CUSTOM AUTOCMDS
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
augroup vimrcEx
  " Clear all autocmds in the group
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
  " Jump to last cursor position unless it's invalid or in an event handler
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal g`\"" |
    \ endif

  "for ruby, autoindent with two spaces, always expand tabs
  autocmd FileType ruby,haml,eruby,yaml,html,javascript,sass,cucumber set ai sw=2 sts=2 et
  autocmd FileType python set sw=4 sts=4 et

  autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.sass setfiletype sass 

  autocmd BufRead *.mkd  set ai formatoptions=tcroqn2 comments=n:&gt;
  autocmd BufRead *.markdown  set ai formatoptions=tcroqn2 comments=n:&gt;

  " Indent p tags
  " autocmd FileType html,eruby if g:html_indent_tags !~ '\\|p\>' | let g:html_indent_tags .= '\|p\|li\|dt\|dd' | endif

  " Don't syntax highlight markdown because it's often wrong
  autocmd! FileType mkd setlocal syn=off

  " Leave the return key alone when in command line windows, since it's used
  " to run commands there.
  autocmd! CmdwinEnter * :unmap <cr>
  autocmd! CmdwinLeave * :call MapCR()
augroup END

" Create the dirs required for a save if they don't exist.
function s:MkNonExDir(file, buf)
  if empty(getbufvar(a:buf, '&buftype')) && a:file!~#'\v^\w+\:\/'
    let dir=fnamemodify(a:file, ':h')
    if !isdirectory(dir)
      call mkdir(dir, 'p')
    endif
  endif
endfunction

augroup BWCCreateDir
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePre * :call s:MkNonExDir(expand('<afile>'), +expand('<abuf>'))
augroup END
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" STATUS LINE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
:set statusline=%<%f\ (%{&ft})\ %-4(%m%)%=%-19(%3l,%02c%03V%)

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" MISC KEY MAPS
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
map <leader>y "*y
" Move around splits with <c-hjkl>
nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j
nnoremap <c-k> <c-w>k
nnoremap <c-h> <c-w>h
nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>l
" Insert a hash rocket with <c-l>
imap <c-l> <space>=><space>
" Can't be bothered to understand ESC vs <c-c> in insert mode
imap <c-c> <esc>
nnoremap <leader><leader> <c-^>
" Close all other windows, open a vertical split, and open this file's test
" alternate in it.
nnoremap <leader>s :call FocusOnFile()<cr>
function! FocusOnFile()
  tabnew %
  normal! v
  normal! l
  call OpenTestAlternate()
  normal! h
endfunction
" Reload in chrome
map <leader>l :w\|:silent !reload-chrome<cr>
" Align selected lines
vnoremap <leader>ib :!align<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" MULTIPURPOSE TAB KEY
" Indent if we're at the beginning of a line. Else, do completion.
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<tab>"
    else
        return "\<c-p>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-n>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" OPEN FILES IN DIRECTORY OF CURRENT FILE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
cnoremap %% <C-R>=expand('%:h').'/'<cr>
map <leader>e :edit %%
map <leader>v :view %%

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" RENAME CURRENT FILE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! RenameFile()
    let old_name = expand('%')
    let new_name = input('New file name: ', expand('%'), 'file')
    if new_name != '' && new_name != old_name
        exec ':saveas ' . new_name
        exec ':silent !rm ' . old_name
        redraw!
    endif
endfunction
map <leader>n :call RenameFile()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" PROMOTE VARIABLE TO RSPEC LET
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! PromoteToLet()
  :normal! dd
  " :exec '?^\s*it\>'
  :normal! P
  :.s/\(\w\+\) = \(.*\)$/let(:\1) { \2 }/
  :normal ==
endfunction
:command! PromoteToLet :call PromoteToLet()
:map <leader>p :PromoteToLet<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" EXTRACT VARIABLE (SKETCHY)
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! ExtractVariable()
    let name = input("Variable name: ")
    if name == ''
        return
    endif
    " Enter visual mode (not sure why this is needed since we're already in
    " visual mode anyway)
    normal! gv

    " Replace selected text with the variable name
    exec "normal c" . name
    " Define the variable on the line above
    exec "normal! O" . name . " = "
    " Paste the original selected text to be the variable value
    normal! $p
endfunction
vnoremap <leader>rv :call ExtractVariable()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" INLINE VARIABLE (SKETCHY)
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! InlineVariable()
    " Copy the variable under the cursor into the 'a' register
    :let l:tmp_a = @a
    :normal "ayiw
    " Delete variable and equals sign
    :normal 2daW
    " Delete the expression into the 'b' register
    :let l:tmp_b = @b
    :normal "bd$
    " Delete the remnants of the line
    :normal dd
    " Go to the end of the previous line so we can start our search for the
    " usage of the variable to replace. Doing '0' instead of 'k$' doesn't
    " work; I'm not sure why.
    normal k$
    " Find the next occurence of the variable
    exec '/\<' . @a . '\>'
    " Replace that occurence with the text we yanked
    exec ':.s/\<' . @a . '\>/' . @b
    :let @a = l:tmp_a
    :let @b = l:tmp_b
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>ri :call InlineVariable()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" MAPS TO JUMP TO SPECIFIC COMMAND-T TARGETS AND FILES
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
map <leader>gr :topleft :split config/routes.rb<cr>
function! ShowRoutes()
  " Requires 'scratch' plugin
  :topleft 100 :split __Routes__
  " Make sure Vim doesn't write __Routes__ as a file
  :set buftype=nofile
  " Delete everything
  :normal 1GdG
  " Put routes output in buffer
  :0r! zeus rake -s routes
  " Size window to number of lines (1 plus rake output length)
  :exec ":normal " . line("$") . "_ "
  " Move cursor to bottom
  :normal 1GG
  " Delete empty trailing line
  :normal dd
endfunction
map <leader>gR :call ShowRoutes()<cr>
map <leader>gv :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT app/views<cr>
map <leader>gc :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT app/controllers<cr>
map <leader>gm :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT app/models<cr>
map <leader>gh :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT app/helpers<cr>
map <leader>gl :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT lib<cr>
map <leader>gp :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT public<cr>
map <leader>gs :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT public/stylesheets<cr>
map <leader>gf :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT features<cr>
map <leader>gg :topleft 100 :split Gemfile<cr>
map <leader>gt :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandTTag<cr>
map <leader>f :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT<cr>
map <leader>F :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT %%<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" SWITCH BETWEEN TEST AND PRODUCTION CODE
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! OpenTestAlternate()
  let new_file = AlternateForCurrentFile()
  exec ':e ' . new_file
endfunction
function! AlternateForCurrentFile()
  let current_file = expand("%")
  let new_file = current_file
  let in_spec = match(current_file, '^spec/') != -1
  let going_to_spec = !in_spec
  let in_app = match(current_file, '\<controllers\>') != -1 || match(current_file, '\<models\>') != -1 || match(current_file, '\<views\>') != -1 || match(current_file, '\<helpers\>') != -1
  if going_to_spec
    if in_app
      let new_file = substitute(new_file, '^app/', '', '')
    end
    let new_file = substitute(new_file, '\.e\?rb$', '_spec.rb', '')
    let new_file = 'spec/' . new_file
  else
    let new_file = substitute(new_file, '_spec\.rb$', '.rb', '')
    let new_file = substitute(new_file, '^spec/', '', '')
    if in_app
      let new_file = 'app/' . new_file
    end
  endif
  return new_file
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>. :call OpenTestAlternate()<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" RUNNING TESTS
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! MapCR()
  nnoremap <cr> :call RunTestFile()<cr>
endfunction
call MapCR()
nnoremap <leader>T :call RunNearestTest()<cr>
nnoremap <leader>a :call RunTests('')<cr>
nnoremap <leader>c :w\|:!script/features<cr>
nnoremap <leader>w :w\|:!script/features --profile wip<cr>

function! RunTestFile(...)
    if a:0
        let command_suffix = a:1
    else
        let command_suffix = ""
    endif

    " Run the tests for the previously-marked file.
    let in_test_file = match(expand("%"), '\(.feature\|_spec.rb\)$') != -1
    if in_test_file
        call SetTestFile()
    elseif !exists("t:grb_test_file")
        return
    end
    call RunTests(t:grb_test_file . command_suffix)
endfunction

function! RunNearestTest()
    let spec_line_number = line('.')
    call RunTestFile(":" . spec_line_number)
endfunction

function! SetTestFile()
    " Set the spec file that tests will be run for.
    let t:grb_test_file=@%
endfunction

function! RunTests(filename)
    " Write the file and run tests for the given filename
    if expand("%") != ""
      :w
    end
    if match(a:filename, '\.feature$') != -1
        exec ":!script/features " . a:filename
    else
        " First choice: project-specific test script
        if filereadable("script/test")
            exec ":!script/test " . a:filename
        " Fall back to the .test-commands pipe if available, assuming someone
        " is reading the other side and running the commands
        elseif filewritable(".test-commands")
          let cmd = 'rspec --color --format progress --require "~/lib/vim_rspec_formatter" --format VimFormatter --out tmp/quickfix'
          exec ":!echo " . cmd . " " . a:filename . " > .test-commands"

          " Write an empty string to block until the command completes
          sleep 100m " milliseconds
          :!echo > .test-commands
          redraw!
        " Fall back to a blocking test run with Bundler
        elseif filereadable("Gemfile")
            exec ":!bundle exec rspec --color " . a:filename
        " Fall back to a normal blocking test run
        else
            exec ":!rspec --color " . a:filename
        end
    end
endfunction


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" CtrlP Configuration
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$'
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f'
let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Md5 COMMAND
" Show the MD5 of the current buffer
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
command! -range Md5 :echo system('echo '.shellescape(join(getline(<line1>, <line2>), '\n')) . '| md5')

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" OpenChangedFiles COMMAND
" Open a split for each dirty file in git
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! OpenChangedFiles()
  only " Close all windows, unless they're modified
  let status = system('git status -s | grep "^ \?\(M\|A\|UU\)" | sed "s/^.\{3\}//"')
  let filenames = split(status, "\n")
  exec "edit " . filenames[0]
  for filename in filenames[1:]
    exec "sp " . filename
  endfor
endfunction
command! OpenChangedFiles :call OpenChangedFiles()

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" InsertTime COMMAND
" Insert the current time
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
command! InsertTime :normal a<c-r>=strftime('%F %H:%M:%S.0 %z')<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" FindConditionals COMMAND
" Start a search for conditional branches, both implicit and explicit
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
command! FindConditionals :normal /\<if\>\|\<unless\>\|\<and\>\|\<or\>\|||\|&&<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Diff tab management: open the current git diff in a tab
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
command! GdiffInTab tabedit %|vsplit|Gdiff
nnoremap <leader>d :GdiffInTab<cr>
nnoremap <leader>D :tabclose<cr>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" RemoveFancyCharacters COMMAND
" Remove smart quotes, etc.
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! RemoveFancyCharacters()
    let typo = {}
    let typo["“"] = '"'
    let typo["”"] = '"'
    let typo["‘"] = "'"
    let typo["’"] = "'"
    let typo["–"] = '--'
    let typo["—"] = '---'
    let typo["…"] = '...'
    :exe ":%s/".join(keys(typo), '\|').'/\=typo[submatch(0)]/ge'
endfunction
command! RemoveFancyCharacters :call RemoveFancyCharacters()

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Selecta Mappings
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Run a given vim command on the results of fuzzy selecting from a given shell
" command. See usage below.
function! SelectaCommand(choice_command, selecta_args, vim_command)
  try
    silent let selection = system(a:choice_command . " | selecta " . a:selecta_args)
  catch /Vim:Interrupt/
    " Swallow the ^C so that the redraw below happens; otherwise there will be
    " leftovers from selecta on the screen
    redraw!
    return
  endtry
  redraw!
  exec a:vim_command . " " . selection
endfunction

" Find all files in all non-dot directories starting in the working directory.
" Fuzzy select one of those. Open the selected file with :e.
nnoremap <leader>f :call SelectaCommand("find * -type f", "", ":e")<cr>

function! SelectaIdentifier()
  " Yank the word under the cursor into the z register
  normal "zyiw
  " Fuzzy match files in the current directory, starting with the word under
  " the cursor
  call SelectaCommand("find * -type f", "-s " . @z, ":e")
endfunction
nnoremap <c-g> :call SelectaIdentifier()<cr>


colorscheme jellybeans
highlight clear SignColumn

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.mobile.erb let b:eruby_subtype='html'
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.mobile.erb set filetype=eruby
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead .pryrc set filetype=ruby

map <silent> <C-N> :silent noh<CR>
map <silent> <C-T> :NERDTree <CR>
map <silent> gb :Gblame<CR>
map <silent> gc :Gcommit<CR>
map <silent> gC :Gcommit -a<CR>
map <silent> gl :gitv<CR>
map <silent> gs :Gstatus<CR>
map <silent> ws :EraseBadWhitespace<CR>

"No arrow keys. :(
inoremap  <Up>     <NOP>
inoremap  <Down>   <NOP>
inoremap  <Left>   <NOP>
inoremap  <Right>  <NOP>
noremap   <Up>     <NOP>
noremap   <Down>   <NOP>
noremap   <Left>   <NOP>
noremap   <Right>  <NOP>
```

Comment: To debug this issue run VIM with the `-u NONE` option (and `-U NONE` if using gvim). If the problem persists then you know it is not your config. If it doesn't then you know it is your config. If the problem is in your config use a binary-search to find out where the problem lies (i.e. comment out half your config file and try it, keep commenting and uncommenting until you find the offending item)

Comment: It does not persist with -u NONE, I'll try bisecting as you suggested.

Comment: I'm glad it is helping; this is a useful way of debugging any problem.

Comment: Also - when you have found out what the problem is - please post it as an answer to the question (that is a good thing to do) so other's can learn what causes this sort of problem.

Comment: A delay could be caused by mappings. Do you have any mapping that start with cw? I think you can check this with `:verbose map cw` and it will also tell you the file where is was last set from.

Comment: Similar to @FDinoff's suggestion:  you might have an `:omap` that starts with `w`.  This would also slow down `dw` etc.  For testing, I tried `:onoremap ww 2w` and got annoying delays with `cw`.  To see if this is the case, try `:verbose omap w`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a comment, and then noticed that the very bottom of your vimrc file shows that I was right.  The culprit is

```
:map <silent> ws :EraseBadWhitespace<CR>
```

According to `:help map-modes`, the `:map` command applies in Normal, Visual, Select, and Operator-pending modes.  After you type `c`, vim enters Operator-pending mode, and then it waits to see if you just want `w` or if you plan to add an `s`.  See also

```
:help 'timeout'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this saved me a lot of time. I just got back to one of my systems to start plugging through, this indeed was the issue